# Restrict access to an application using oauth2_proxy and Gitlab as its provider

Tags: oauth-2.0, gitlab

I have currently set up a web-based application, to which I have added an authentication method using oauth2_proxy (with gitlab as authentication provider). What I need to know is if there's way that I can restrict the access to this app using a Gitlab group or something like that? Because as of now - oauth is configured to allow access to any user on gitlab which has a @foor.bar email domain (`-email-domain=foo.bar` directive on oauth config). However I'm looking to control this method in a more restricted manner, so for instance I will create a group on Gitlab, to which I will add only relevant users & other groups to which access should be granted. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: I'm afraid not, ended up not using it. Although it's been almost two years since I posted that question so who knows, it might be supported now :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer releases, access can be restricted to a gitlab group in the [oauth2_proxy configuration](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/configuration/overview/#command-line-options).

```
--gitlab-group="your_auth_group"
```

in `oauth2-proxy.cfg`:

```
gitlab_groups: [
  "your_auth_group",
  "group2"
]
```

Be aware, that without that configuration, anyone who can login to your Gitlab instance can use your oauth2_proxy-protected service, independent of where the application is registered.

Registering an appliation in a GitLab group does not restrict the users!

You can also use `--gitlab-projects` to restrict by access level to a gitlab project. Check [documentation](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/configuration/overview/#command-line-options) for details

Tip: you can see the list of groups of an authenticated user using the `/oauth2/userinfo` [endpoint](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/features/endpoints).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's what you're looking for but regards [documentation](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/configuration/overview) you could use `--authenticated-emails-file` param to provide authenticated emails list.

Comment: Thanks! That seems like a relatively newer addition since I posted this question (4 and something years ago) and have abandoned that project a while ago, but thanks for posting that answer for others that may come across this requirement!